# Switching pages with history.push() passing state - React Router 5

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, history.js

I want to switch between pages. 
I'm pushing path and a `{state}` object. 
The problem is that when pressing the browser back button its going endless back and forth between Signup and Signin even though I switch only twice or more. 
Or when pressing the browser back button the URL changes to signin or signup but the page will be my 404 component, or to the `Main` page (in the sandbox) regardless what was the page before.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/Eladossa/signin-signup-back-fails/tree/main/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The two components are in a conditional rendering

```
 {auth ? (
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/signup" auth={auth}>
              <SignUp setAuth={setAuth} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signin" auth={auth}>
              <SignIn setAuth={setAuth} />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        ) :
```

when switching from signup to signin in a button -

```
history.push({
          pathname: "/signin",
          state: { from: "fromSignUp" }
        });
```

Pressing the browser back button on each component will check in the history if it came from signup or signin -

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.onpopstate = () => {
      console.log("useEffect SignUp", location.state?.from === "fromSignIn"); // sometimes true/sometimes false, even when came from 'signin'
      if (location.state?.from === "fromSignIn") {
        history.push({
          pathname: "/signin",
          state: { from: "fromSignUp" }
        });
      } else {
        setAuth(false);
        history.goBack();
      }
    };
  }, [location.state, history]);
```

In my VS Code its acting even worse .

I can give a link to the GitHub repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found.
 Thanks to a friend of mine I found that don't need any of this   conditions, functions and push() -

###### Removed -

```
const [auth setAuth] = useState(false)  // no need

 window.onpopstate = () => {   // no need
 history.push({    // no need
          pathname: "/signin",
          state: { from: "fromSignUp" }
        });
```

The solution is with two per of `<Switch>`. The `Route`'s closing tag for  Header (the navbar) -  `<Route> <Header/>` - `</Route>` is below all  other components inside the inner `Switch`

I'm not showing the props here. 
**App.js**

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/signup">
          <SignUp />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signin">
          <SignIn />
        </Route>
        <Route >
          <Header />
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/"  >
                <Main />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/pageone" >
                <PageOne />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/pagetwo"  >
                <PageTwo />
              </Route>
              <Route component={PageNotFound} path="*" />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

All works as it should, Perfect. Thanks to David

Answer (score 1):

First of all: in your app.js you say: if auth == true then show signup/signin. auth needs to be false in this case. then add a new route path="*" and redirect it to signup as example.
Then in your SignUp component in the useEffect function you say: come from SignIn then.... "ELSE" (and here is the error) you say:

```
    setAuth(false);
    history.goBack();
```

So you set setAuth to false. In this case you can never navigate back from page 2 to page 1 as example. This page are only visible if auth is true.

Greetings, Flo